# How to set react-final-form onSubmit values param type TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-final-form

How can I set change the value type of onSubmit in react-final-form.

```
inteface IValues {
    name: string;
}
<Form onSubmit={(values: IValues) => {}}>   // Error happens here
//    Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
//    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IFormValues': name
```

---

This works but I can't get the value.name

```
<Form onSubmit={(values: object) => {
    // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'
    values.name
}}>
```

---

I can cast to IValues as below to extract name.

```
<Form onSubmit={(values: object) => {
    const { name } = values as IValues;
}}>
```

onSubmit is from Config, I tried finding how to set FormData type but couldn't find one.
Is there anyway I can set FormData in jsx?
And is there any other option I can do better?

Comment: hello, did you solve this ?

Comment: No not yet. Still specifically casting type

Comment: This is currently impossible because of a limitation in react-final-form's TypeScript definitions. There's a PR open to fix it. https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/pull/426

Answer (score 4):

`react-final-form` supports value typing as of version [6.1.0](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/releases/tag/v6.1.0).

You can achieve it by simply providing generic type to `Form` component.

```js
import { withTypes } from 'react-final-form'

inteface IValues {
    name: string;
}

const { Form } = withTypes<IValues>()

<Form onSubmit={(values: IValues) => {}}>
```